# MS-Access: Slow queries on linked CSV files

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, ms-access-2016

My Access 2016 db has links to several CSV files, some of them quite big (>120MB). When running complex queries on these CSV files, the speed is too slow to be practical. I cannot make local tables of these linked CSV files because after every cycle of running queries, these CSV files are refreshed with updated data by an external server.

What can I do to speed things up significantly?

Comment: Do not use CSV files for querying purposes as @ThunderFrame explains below. CSVs are text files usually used for migrating/porting data across systems or archiving and should not be used in applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be wise to import the CSV data to local temporary/staging tables. You can then run queries against the temporary table, and if the query needs to use joins, or is very complex, you can consider using indexes on the temporary table as appropriate.

Once you're done with querying the data, you can truncate or drop the temporary tables.

Comment: I sort of knew this trick but the problem is that the database file size very quickly gets to 2GB and auto-compacting the db is not easy

Comment: The temporary tables don't have to be in the same database. You don't get all of the speed, but linked Access tables are faster than linked CSV files.

Comment: even if i make a new db for temp tables; if i keep overwriting them, that new db size balloons and need to be regularly compacted otherwise it stops working at 2GB.

Comment: @Kashif as ThunderFrame is trying to explain, you can separate the temp tables across multiple Access files and link all into one mdb/accdb to overcome the 2GB which is a limit of **one** individual Access file.

Comment: You can either compact the remote db using automation, or just create and link to a temporary db on-the-fly.

Comment: @ThunderFrame: Very interesting idea, creating a temp db on the fly.

Comment: @ThunderFrame: Choosing your answer as correct. I suggest you add the bit about temp db in the answer since that is what solves the db compaction issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to *load* (not exactly the same as *import*) the CSV files into *MySQL*:

[Import CSV File Into MySQL Table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)

This is a *very* fast process - close to a simple file copy.

Then use *MyODBC* to connect to the MySQL instance via ODBC.

Comment: When did MySQL come into the conversation?

Comment: Given the requirements / constraints, this seems like a good approach.